# Changing the attribute of different anchor tag to same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new in JS and jQuery. I'm trying to  make dynamic page selector button via jQuery. The problem is when I try to change attribute and text of 3 anchor tags with different IDs, all the value of 3 anchor tags change to last value.

Let's say:

```
currentSlide=2;
slideToShow=3;
```

Then when the following code gets executed all the 3 anchor tags became same with i.e.

```
<a onclick="loadmore(4);return false" id="anchor4">4</a>
```

The jQuery code is:

```
$("a#anchor"+(currentSlide-1)).text((slideToShow-1)).attr({onclick:"loadmore("+(slideToShow-1)+");return false",id:"anchor"+(slideToShow-1)});
$("a#anchor"+currentSlide).text(slideToShow).attr({onclick:"loadmore("+slideToShow+");return false",id:"anchor"+slideToShow});
$("a#anchor"+(currentSlide+1)).text((slideToShow+1)).attr({onclick:"loadmore("+(slideToShow+1)+");return false",id:"anchor"+(slideToShow+1)});
```

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Setting `onclick` _attributes_ via jQuery? You got to be kidding. Write that properly and use `.on`

Comment: do not use attr to set onclick....

Comment: why i can't change onclick attribute via jquery?

Comment: ok but my problem is not that

Comment: your issue is within the wrong way you set onclick through attr, bound values by reference passing objects in this way. 
Change the code to set the onclick using the on and it should work fine